# Creating something similar to a Zip or CombineLatest of IObservables that does not fire all outputs when one updates

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, combinators

See below the C# code for a Combinator that zips together two inputs

```
public class TransformScript
{
    public IObservable<Tuple<bool,bool>> Process(IObservable<bool> source1, IObservable<bool> source2)
    {
        return source1.Zip(source2,(s1,s2) => Tuple.Create(s1,s2));
    }
}
```

This code takes in two input streams of booleans and then fires a tuple whenever both of the slots in the zip are filled.  In contrast, a CombineLatest waits for the tuple to fill for the first time (and then fires) and thereafter fires whenever one of the slots is updated, even if the other remains static.

I would like a behaviour that is similar, in some sense, to both of these, but very different in a key way for which I think using a Tuple is probably not wise.

Each time an element is received from a given output stream (say source1), that element should be passed forward without the other stream yielding an output.  I am, in effect, compressing the two output streams into a single output stream which yields labelled output, so that I can pass that single object through a bottle neck.  Explicitly attaching a label to each stream, merging them into a new stream and then extracting the elements based off the label posthoc is not an option.

Another illustration is to compare to a merge (note that the objects in my case are of the same type).  See the marble diagram below for the merge operator

```
source 1  -----1-----1-----1-----
source 2  ---2----2---------2----
merge     ---m-m--m--m-----mm----
```

Here the output is only a single stream which is all my bottleneck can take, but the identity of the different items has been lost

```
source 1  -----1-----1-----1-----
source 2  ---2----2---------2----
whatIwant ---2-1--2--1-----12----
```

This would allow me to, on the other side of the bottleneck instantly seperate out two streams to recover source 1 and source 2.  But again, I want to do so without adding labels to them.

How can I modify (or completely rewrite) the code above to acheive this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, I originally had 3 streams but I thought I would simplify it down to just the minimum.  I would correct the question now

Comment: Okay, I will try to further clarify with a marble diagram and a comparison to the merge operator

Comment: Is `source1.Merge(source2)` an answer to your question?

Comment: No, because then the two items are indistinguishable after the fact.

Comment: So you are searching for a way to distinguish the items using an invisible attribute or something? If this is the question, I don't know the answer, and I will very surprised if an answer exists.

Comment: I can’t write out a full answer now, but it looks like you want the DiscriminatedUnion functionality from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42164179/415661.

Comment: @Pablo How do you want to check if the object is coming from the first observable or the second observable if you don't want to add any information where the objects are coming from? Why is "attaching a label" not an option for you, specially when you remove the label again? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of how you want to merge/combine your observables into one observable and how you want to separate them again (and why).

Answer (score -1):

Use an [Either monad](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium/blob/b5fc85f0257ad4b70c4fd74a6ecb4dfa267087e9/dotnet/src/Sodium/CSharp/Sodium.Functional/Either.cs#L142) with the following code:

```cs
public class TransformScript
{
    public IObservable<Either<T1,T2>> Process<T1,T2>(IObservable<T1> source1, IObservable<T2> source2)
    {
        return Observable.Merge(
            source1.Select(value => Either.First(value)),
            source2.Select(value => Either.Second(value))
        );
    }
}
```

You can then [discriminate between First or Second parts](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium/blob/b5fc85f0257ad4b70c4fd74a6ecb4dfa267087e9/dotnet/src/Sodium/CSharp/Sodium.Functional/Either.cs#L207) of the Either monad later in the RX pipeline.

Comment: The OP has specified that *"the objects in my case are of the same type"*. So there is not `T1` and `T2`, but just `T`.